# Using arcpy update cursor to populate a field based on subtraction from two other fields

Tags: arcpy, cursor, typeerror

In a counties shapefile, I have two fields named population2001 and population2010. I would like to create a third field with the difference between 2001 and 2010 using arcpy and the update cursor to better learn how to use cursors.
My code:

```
   import arcpy
   arcpy.env.workspace =          
   r"C:\Users\Documents\geodatabase.gdb"
   ndCounties = r"C:\Users\Documents\geodatabase.gdb\Counties"
   #add the new field
   arcpy.AddField_management(ndCounties, "difference", "LONG", field_length = 10)

   fields = ['POP2001', 'POP2010', 'difference']

   with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(ndCounties, fields) as cursor:
      for row in cursor:
         if row[0] == 'POP2001':
            row[1] = 1
            row[2] = 2
         elif row[0] == 'POP2010':
            row[1] = 2
            row[2] = 3
         row[3] = row[1] - row[2]
         cursor.updateRow(row)
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'

I'm not exactly sure if this is the right way of doing this field subtraction.

Comment: As a side note, the field_length parameter for AddField_management is only applicable on fields of type text or blob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your cursor the row followed by the number references each field:

- `row[0]` references `POP2001` field
- `row[1]` references `POP2010` field
- `row[2]` references `difference` field

You do not have a fourth field to reference with `row[3]`.

What you want to do is subtract `row[0]` from `row[1]` to get the difference to put into `row[2]`.

```
for row in cursor:
    row[2] = abs(row[1] - row[0])
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

The `abs()` gives an absolute value.  If you want to see where population has gone down (a negative difference) remove the `abs()`:

```
row[2] = row[1] - row[0]
```